# Why is the return of `QtGui.QValidator.validate` so inconsistent? Robust way to handle this?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside, pyqt5

I am trying to develop an app that uses Qt. I am trying to get the app to use both `PySide` and `PyQt4`. I have not had any major compatibility issues except for my custom `QtGui.QValidator` class:

```
import sys
import os
import re

variant = 'PyQt4'
#variant = 'PySide'

print 'Python {}, {}'.format(sys.version, sys.platform)

# Using PyQt4:
if variant == 'PySide':
    import PySide
    from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
    print 'PySide {}, Qt {}'.format(PySide.__version__, PySide.QtCore.__version__)

# Using PySide:
if variant == 'PyQt4':
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
    from PyQt4.Qt import PYQT_VERSION_STR
    print 'PyQt4 {}, Qt {}'.format(PYQT_VERSION_STR, QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)

class ExpressionValidator(QtGui.QValidator):
    def __init__(self, parent=None,):
        QtGui.QValidator.__init__(self, parent)

        self.states = {'invalid':      QtGui.QValidator.Invalid,
                      'intermediate':  QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate,
                      'acceptable':    QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable,
                      }

        self.regX_expression = re.compile('([0-9.eEpiPI+-/*\(\))\^]*)')

    def returnState(self, state, text, pos):

        if state == 'acceptable':
            color = '#00cc00' # green
        elif state == 'intermediate':
            color = '#fff79a' # yellow
        else:
            color = '#f6989d' # red
        self.parent().setStyleSheet('QLineEdit {{ background-color: {} }}'.format(color))

        if variant == 'PySide':
            return self.states[state]
        else:
            return (self.states[state], pos)


    def validate(self, textInput, pos):
        # Check text, return state
        matches = self.regX_expression.findall(textInput)
        if matches and len(matches[0]) == len(textInput):
            if len(textInput) >0 and str(textInput)[-1] in '+-/*^':
                self.parent().setToolTip('Expression Needs Finished.')
                return self.returnState('intermediate', textInput, pos)
            else:
                return self.returnState('acceptable', textInput, pos)
        else:
            return self.returnState('invalid', textInput, pos)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('GTK')
    mainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()

    lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
    lineEdit.setValidator(ExpressionValidator(lineEdit))

    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(lineEdit)
    mainWindow.show()

    app.exec_()

    app.deleteLater()
    sys.exit()
```

I need robust code to be placed in the `returnState` function. Do I just have to test this on multiple systems and continue to build my `if` statements?

So far these calls work:

- Python 2.7.6, Windows 7, PyQt4 4.10.4, Qt 4.8.6:

  - `return (self.states[state], pos)`
- Python 2.7.6, Windows 7, PySide 1.2.1, Qt 4.8.6:

  - `return self.states[state]`
  - `return (self.states[state], text, pos)`
- Python 2.7.8, OpenSuse (linux2), PyQt4 4.10.4, Qt 4.8.5:

  - `return (self.states[state], pos)`
- Python 2.7, OpenSuse (linux2), PyQt4 4.8.3, Qt 4.7.1:

  - `return (self.states[state], pos)`
- Python 2.7.8, OpenSuse (linux2), PySide 1.2.1, Qt 4.8.5:

  - `return self.states[state]`
  - `return (self.states[state], text, pos)`

What about parsing `help(QtGui.QValidator.validate)` for the correct call and dynamically creating the return call based on this?

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). At the moment, it's impossible to test your example, because `qtwrapper` cannot imported, and in any case the code does nothing. Also, you have not said what versions of PyQt/PySide you are using on the various platforms you are trying to support.

Comment: Updated with functional example, various combinations tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

As pointed out by Onlyjus in the comments, the exact behaviour differs depending on [which PyQt api](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) is being used.

With the v1 api, the `input` argument will be a `QString`, which means that it can be modified in place (which is how the C++ api works). But with the v2 api, the `input` argument is an immutable python string, and so it has to be returned instead. So the actual signatures are:

```
# v1 api (default for Python 2)
QValidator.validate(QString, int) -> (QValidator.State, int)
# v2 api (default for Python 3)
QValidator.validate(str, int) -> (QValidator.State, str, int)
```

These (and many other) differences are documented in the [PyQt4 and Python v3](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/python_v3.html) section of the PyQt4 documentation.

The PySide behaviour, although slightly strange, is at least predictable. It will allow a tuple *of any length at all* to be returned, so long as the types of the first three values tally with the C++ signature. So any of these will work:

```
    return (QValidator.State,)
    return (QValidator.State, "string")
    return (QValidator.State, "string", 10)
    return (QValidator.State, "string", 10, "foo", 60, "blah")
```

But none of that flexibility helps in the current situation, because PyQt4 just cannot match any of those variants when using the v1 api.

It looks like the only real solution is to switch to the v2 api (for `QString`, at least).

However, if you cannot do that, the best compromise would be to use something very similar to what you are already doing:

```
    if variant == 'PyQt4':
        # if necessary, modify text in place here
        # rather than returning it
        return (self.states[state], pos)
    else:
        return (self.states[state], text, pos)
```

This should work with PySide, PyQt4, and also PyQt5 (should you ever chose to provide support for that as well).

Comment: It seems that depending on what api is being used for PyQt4, the call changes. For api 1: (state, pos), for api 2: (state, text, pos). Using help(QtGui.QValidator.validate) seems to give the correct documentation...

Comment: @Onlyjus. Well spotted! I've updated my answer with a more accurate explanation. Sorry if my original answer mislead you.

Comment: I have found that the `sip.getapi(QtGui.QValidator.validate)` is unreliable when running other programs that use a Qt wrapper (like spyder because it changes the api, and sets it). The link to the documentation doesn't even say that there are two apis for `QtGui.QValidator.validate` What a mess...

Comment: @Onlyjus. Your `sip.getapi` call makes no sense. You need to do `sip.getapi('QString')`, to get the relevant api version number. The link doesn't mention the different signatures for `validate`, because it is only indirectly related to that topic. The more specific differences are all listed in [this section](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/python_v3.html), which includes the relevant info regarding `QValidator`. (I removed this link when I last edited my answer, but I've put it back now).